# docker-compose down does not cascade down SIGTERM through two layers of bash scripts

Tags: bash, docker, signals

I have two bash scripts, one as an entrypoint to my docker container, looking like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sig_handler() 
{
  echo "[LAYER1] killing children with pid "$pid
  [[ $pid ]] && kill $pid
  exit 1
}

trap 'sig_handler' SIGINT SIGTERM

while true; do
  ./nextlayer.sh & pid=$!
  wait $pid
  echo "Waiting 5 seconds before starting a new worker..."
  sleep 5
done
```

Now *nextlayer.sh* has some kind of signal trapping too, BUT also tries to clean up some stuff, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

sig_handler() 
{
  echo "[LAYER2] Exiting main script and cleaning up tasks"
  cleanup
}

cleanup() 
{
  echo "[LAYER2] Cleaning up"
  sleep 5
  echo "Cleanup done, exiting with SIGTERM"
  exit 143
}

trap 'sig_handler' SIGINT SIGTERM

i=0
while [ $i -lt 10 ]
do
  i=$(( $i + 1 ))
  sleep 1
  echo $i
done
```

This just loops over i while i is < 10 and echoes the result every second. When running the entrypoint script locally without docker and pressing ctrl + c to exit, the script terminates as expected and outputs the cleanup function content.

However, when applying the same logic onto a docker container, the SIGTERM only reaches the sighandler in the entrypoint script, but never in the second layer script. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain in detail how docker is involved? Do you run both scripts inside one docker container, or does the first script and the second script run in different environments (e.g. one outside docker and the other inside, or both in different docker containers).

Comment: both run in docker, the first one is the entrypoint script that calls the second one. I found the solution and posted it as an answer below :)

Comment: Can you delete both layers of wrapper and just set the main container `CMD` to directly run the worker?  If you need multiple worker processes, launch multiple containers off the same image.

Comment: @DavidMaze our use case is basically replicating something like a systemd service for docker. So the entrypoint does the while true loop and sleeps for n seconds until it starts another worker. So just calling the worker from CMD wont do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

in the sig_handler function of the entrypoint script, the following wait instruction solves it:

```
sig_handler() 
{
    echo "[LAYER1] killing children with pid "$pid
    [[ $pid ]] && kill $pid
    wait $pid # this is crucial
    exit 1
}
```

So before actually quitting the container, the wait $pid forces it to actually wait out the exit from the subsequent script. I tested this 5 iterations of scripts, it all works.